# Clear paper-dropdown-menu value

Tags: meteor, polymer, polymer-1.0

I can't find a way to clear a paper-dropdown-menu. I would like to reset it to its initial state when my form is sent (ajax). I can't find anything in the demos or doc.

I'm using meteor and polymer 1.0.

Thanks a lot

Here's some code:

```
            <paper-dropdown-menu label="List's Color Tag" id="colorTag">
                <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                    {{#each colors}}
                        <paper-item>{{.}}</paper-item>
                    {{/each}}
                </paper-menu>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe with some snippets of your code or a plunker/jsfiddle...

Answer (score 3):

Set the current selected item to null.
This was recently fixed.
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/pull/47

Comment: Even if I give a paper-dropdown-menu an id like "dropdown" and I do document.getElementById("dropdown").selected = null;, it has no effect. I looked over the github but I can't find any clear examples of it; only changes in Polymer itself.

Comment: Something like this might work:

`document.querySelector('paper-dropdown-menu')._setSelectedItem(null);`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and digged quite deep into the polymer code - it seems like there is no way for doing this. I found a quite dirty workaround, using an invisible item, but maybe it helps for you :

```
 <paper-dropdown-menu label="List's Color Tag" id="colorTag">
                <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
                   <paper-item style="display:none"></paper-item>
                    {{#each colors}}
                        <paper-item>{{.}}</paper-item>
                    {{/each}}
                </paper-menu>
            </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Than you should be able to set it to display nothing as selected by calling

```
document.getElementById('colorTag').contentElement.selected = 0;
```

I hope it works for you, it is not tested completely as I don't use Meteor and I use special IDs. I have set the invisible item to have the ID -1, so it does not mess with my other IDs.

So in my case it looks like this :

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="carSelector"
                             label="[[label]]" attr-for-selected="car-id"
                             selected="{{selectedId}}" always-float-label
                >
            <paper-menu attr-for-selected="car-id"
                        selected="{{selectedId}}" class="dropdown-content">
                <paper-item car-id="-1" style="display:none"></paper-item>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[cars]]" as="c">
                    <paper-item car-id$="[[c.Id]]">
                        <paper-item-body>
                            [[c.Plate]]
                        </paper-item-body>
                    </paper-item>
                </template>
            </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

And the corresponding call :

```
this.selectedId=-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add a `selected` attribute to the `paper-drop-down` first children (In this case the `paper-menu`)

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="List's Color Tag" id="colorTag">
 <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selectedItem}}">
   {{#each colors}}
   <paper-item>{{.}}</paper-item>
   {{/each}}
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Then, when you want to reset it, just assign the `selectedItem` value to null

```
this.selectedItem = null
```